# Passing values to array in customized format

Tags: php

I am reading a line from an input file and passing it to an array.

My input file contains only one line: **1 false A 2,3**

Where 1=vertex, false=visited, A=letter, 2,3=neighbours

I am passing the line to array using the code below ..

```
$data = array(
        1 => array($lines[2]));
```

and i get the following result:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [0] => 1 false A 2,3 ) )
```

Every thing is working perfectly, the only thing i want now is to assign each value to an attribute like 1 should be assigned to vertex and so on ...

Example:

```
Array ( [1] => Array ( [vertex] => 1 [visited] => [letter] => A [neighbours] => Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 3 ) ) )
```

Is there any way to get the same result?

Comment: you can use explode with space as delimter, can maniputes things as you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that with [explode()](https://www.php.net/explode) like below;

```
<?php

$values = explode(" ", $lines[2]);

$inputArr = array(
    'vertex' => $values[0],
    'visited' => $values[1],
    'letter' => $values[2],
    'neighbours' => explode(",", $values[3])
);
```

**Edit:** If you want to use multiple lines, you can use;

```
<?php
$inputsArr = array();


$handle = fopen("your_file.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $values = explode(" ", line);

        $inputArr = array(
            'vertex' => $values[0],
            'visited' => $values[1],
            'letter' => $values[2],
            'neighbours' => explode(",", $values[3]
        );

        array_push($inputsArr, $inputArr);
    }
} else {
    die("Error occured while opening file")
}
```

Comment: ohh my gosh!. now i have to close my editor because God copied mine code to someelse's mind.....

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Huseyin.The answer was very clear but now i am stuck in the case when there will be multiple lines in the file. How would i pass each line to array in the same manner?